# How to get salable qty in magento 2.3.3?

Tags: stock, qty, product-view-page, salable

How to get **salable qty** of each Product and display in Product view page.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');
$qty = $StockState->execute($_product->getSku());
echo ($qty[0]['qty']);
?>
```

You can get only the **saleable quantity** by the following above code.

Comment: How can I check saleable qty of product in current quote?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to get salable QTY.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface');
    $qty = $StockState->execute($_product->getSku(), 2);
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this one and got answer.
Here you mentioned **2** manually.It is stock_id.
How to get stock_id dynamically and update salable qty?

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following code :-**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\ModelName;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;
class ClassName
{
    private $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    public function __construct(
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
    ) {
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $sku = "testsku"; //pass your product sku
        $salable = $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($sku);
        echo json_encode($salable);
    }
}
```

**Output :-**

```
[{"stock_name":"Default Stock","qty":4,"manage_stock":true}]
```

[Reference Link](https://webkul.com/blog/get-salable-quantity-in-magento-2-3/)

Comment: It's showing array of stock information.I need to show only **salable qty**.
How to get only **salable qty**, not stock name,manage stock? @Rk Rathod

Comment: as per example salable qty is 4

Answer (score 0):

Loop stock qty or sum the stock you need

Comment: output the array value in second position