# Magento2.4: How to get Salable quantity in list.phtml file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

How can i get salable quantity in list.phtml file, I want to show label on those products which have 0 salable quantity.

Comment: Refer this link to get salable qty [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302187/99520](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302187/99520)

Comment: how do I pass each product SKU in parameters when calling this function?

Comment: The object manager is bad practice.

Comment: You implement the same functionality without using object manager. This is a hint only not a solution.

Comment: Payaray Afzel, why do yo delete your questions on this platform with accepted answers? the answers are lost - maybe other people have the same questions like you. and this is the goal of this platform... i answered two questions, you deleted the questions (and my answer too). my reputation is gone away. please do not delete your questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Output" />

</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Helper**

**Output.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Filter\Template;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;

/**
 * Html output
 */
class Output extends \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output
{
    /**
     * Array of existing handlers
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_handlers;

    /**
     * Template processor instance
     *
     * @var Template
     */
    protected $_templateProcessor = null;

    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;

    /**
     * Eav config
     *
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $_eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $directivePatterns;

    /**
     * @var GetSalableQuantityDataBySku
     */
    private $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;

    /**
     * Output constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param array $directivePatterns
     * @param array $handlers
     * @param GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Config $eavConfig,
        Data $catalogData,
        Escaper $escaper,
        $directivePatterns = [],
        array $handlers = [],
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
    ) {
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->directivePatterns = $directivePatterns;
        $this->_handlers = $handlers;
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
        parent::__construct($context, $eavConfig, $catalogData, $escaper, $directivePatterns, $handlers);
    }

    public function getProductSalableQty($prdSku)
    {
        return $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($prdSku);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product**

**list.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $_helper */
$_helper = $block->getData('outputHelper');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty">
        <div><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() === 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info"
                     id="product-item-info_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_product->getId() ?>"
                     data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = 'left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                       class="product photo product-item-photo"
                       tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                <?=/* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')?>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                                /* Add Salable Qty */
                                $qty = $_helper->getProductSalableQty($_product->getSku());
                                $SalableQty = 0;
                                if (isset($qty[0]['qty'])) {
                                    $SalableQty = $qty[0]['qty'];
                                }
                             ?>
                             <br/>
                            <span>Salable Qty : <?= $SalableQty ?> </span>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                        <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()):?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                              data-product-sku="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                              action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                              method="post">
                                            <?php $optionsData = $block->getData('viewModel')->getOptionsData($_product); ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($optionsData as $optionItem): ?>
                                                <input type="hidden"
                                                       name="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($optionItem['name']) ?>"
                                                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($optionItem['value']) ?>">
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="product"
                                                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                   value="<?=
                                                   /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]
                                                    ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary"
                                                    disabled>
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else:?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()):?>
                                            <div class="stock available">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else:?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ?
                                    /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-primary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary">
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ?
                                    /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                        $position,
                                        'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.actions-secondary'
                                    ) : '' ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute(
                                        $_product,
                                        $_product->getShortDescription(),
                                        'short_description'
                                    ) ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ?
                /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                    $position,
                    'product-item-info_' . $_product->getId() . ' div.product-item-actions'
                ) : '' ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getChildBlock('toolbar')->setIsBottom(true)->toHtml() ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?= $escaper->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Output:**
[image]